# Excel vba script to count occurrences of a number in given range of limits

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a vba script that can find numbers greater than 5, 10 & 15 in a specific column then take count of them i.e. how many numbers are greater than 5 (let's say and so for 10 and 15 as well).

Sample Output (needed):

```
Gt5  Gt10  Gt20
23    34    90
```

Comment: Have a look at the `COUNTIF` function, there is no need for a macro.

Comment: But How do I club 2 condition in COUNTIF? 
e.g. >0 && <=5 this kind of range.

Comment: In this case you have to use `COUNTIFS` like `=COUNTIFS(J3:J13,">= 0",J3:J13, "<= 5")`